# issue with linking pages in my python server

Tags: python, server

I created a basic server using python and it is working, but only for the index page which is placed inside the defined folder. There are more html pages linked to the index page.

this is my file structure

```
 - myServer.py

 - roses(this is a folder)

     -index.html

     -contact_us.html

     -about_us.html
```

index.html, contact_us.html, about_us.html pages are inside the roses folder.

**this is my server code**

```
from os import curdir, sep
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        try:
            if self.path == "/":
                self.path = "roses/index.html"
            if self.path.endswith(".html"):
                f = open(curdir+sep+self.path, 'rb')
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(f.read())
                f.close()
                return
            return        
        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)

try:
    server = HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 9000), MyHandler)
    print('My python server is started...')
    print('Press ^C to stop.')
    server.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('shutting down my python server...')
    print('server stopped !')
    server.socket.close()
```

there are links for contact_us.html and about_us.html pages in the index page. But when I click on them `error 404` is shown. 
If I put those pages(contact_us.html ans about_us.html) in the same location where server code is situated(outside the roses folder), it works.

I know I have to configure it using self path like I have done here

```
if self.path == "/":
      self.path = "roses/index.html"
```

But I cannot figure out how to configure it. Help me in this case.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include "roses" in all cases. If you don't, then the system will try to look for the html pages in the root directory. This works for / because you are adding "roses" already. Try /index.php, it will break,

Suggested fix:

```
if self.path == "/":
    self.path = "/index.html"
if self.path.endswith(".html"):
    f = open(curdir+sep+'roses'+sep+self.path, 'rb')
```

Comment: Also consider using [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to construct your paths rather than string concatenation.